# restore the customization from publishing site to team site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have customized the design in publishing site but i can't save the site as template , therefore i need to restore the customized design site to team site to be able to save the site as template with my custom design !!

Is it possible to Restore-SPSite with publish template on a team site?

Comment: is it root level site collection or susbite

Comment: both, I face the two situations

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to save the customizations easily for that site.  Instead, recreate the customizations in a new team site (without publishing).  Then you can use that site as a template.

Take the changes that you made to the MasterPage and apply them to the MasterPage in a Team Site via 'Change the look'.  Before starting, make sure the masterpage is uploaded to the MasterPage gallery for that site.

[Follow these instructions](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/07/21/sharepoint-2013-how-to-change-the-master-page-of-your-sharepoint-site/).

1. From Site Settings, click 'Change the look' under 'Look and Feel'

[image: Change The Look]

2. On the Themes page click on the theme that you are using. (Likely the first theme if you haven't changed the theme before)

[image: Click the theme]

3. Next on the left pane you can select the master page for this theme.

[image: Select the layout]

4. Next click on “Try it Out” and then “Yes, keep it”
5. Now you can create a template using this site.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will set your answer, let me apply your steps and feedback you.

Answer (score 1):

`Backup-SPSite` takes everything in the site, including GUIDs, thus you cannot use `Restore-SPSite` to restore to a new site in the same content database since those GUIDs already exist in the DB.  You would see the following error if you attempted this:

> Restore-SPSite : The operation that you are attempting to perform
>   cannot be completed  successfully. No content databases in the web
>   application were available  to store your site collection. The
>   existing content databases may have  reached the maximum number of
>   site collections, or be set to read-only,  or be offline, **or may**
>   **already contain a copy of this site collection.**  Create another
>   content database for the Web application and then try the  operation
>   again.

You could however restore the site to a different content database.  This should work, even with sites using the Publishing infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you for your information, Is that mean the customization will be restored as publishing site or team site! i need to move the customization from publishing site to team site

Comment: I'm sorry I missed that critical part of the question.  How have you customized the site?  Some customizations can only be done on publishing sites (such as page layouts).

Comment: just master page modifications,

Answer (score 1):

What i believe, if you customized the Publishing Site master page then you cannot use it on team site as this required the Publishing feature enabled on the target site. If you enable the Publishing feature on team site then Save as template will be disabled.

I would a create brand new publishing site then  customize the master page. Once all customization completed then export the site, then you can import this